# How to access module from different project in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-router

I have two different projects(app1, app2) deployed in the same domain and I want to access app2 module inside app1 to avoid code duplication. Is this possible to do that?

> I'm using angular-cli - Angular 4